# What apps to sync movie subtitles easily are available for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, subtitle

I have a subtitle file that is about 3 to 4 seconds behind. What tools can I use to automatically move all the times in the subtitle file so they are correct with the time of the movie? Something that I can for example just add the time I want to add and it will add this time to the synced times in the subtitle files without having to edit each line individually.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I'm surprised no one mentioned this:

## [gnome-subtitles](http://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-subtitles) [image: Install gnome-subtitles]

It has impressive features, it's extremely easy to use and very well-polished. A lot of care and detail in its UI (check the char count in each line).

I use it all the time to shift subtitle timings to/from HDTV to BDRip/DVDRip releases.

[image: gnome-suttitles]

Side-note: VLC player has on-the-fly subtitle timing shift. It will not change your `.srt` file, only the playback, but it's very convenient for movies you'll only watch once and don't care about saving the adjustments. I assign them to UP and DOWN directional keys.

Extra info (which was hard to figure out): To shift multiple subtitles back or forward together, select the subtitles and use the menu option `Timings > Adjust`. Now you can adjust the timing of the first and last subtitles you've selected, and all the selected subtitles will get shifted by the number of seconds you choose.

Answer (score 19):

With [Gaupol](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gaupol) you can edit the subtitles. Select the text you want to adjust, then go to "Tools" > "Shift Positions" and change as you like.

[image]

[image]

---

*If you don't want to edit the subtitles:*
Although it does not make a "permanent change", with [VLC](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/vlc) you can do that with the movie you are seeing. Just go to "Tools" > "Track Synchronization".

[image]

Comment: Thanks desgua. I already use the G/H keys from VLC to achieve this but I want a permanent solution. Some tool that reads a SRT, Sub or any subtitle file and changes the time.

Comment: Then you may use some editor like Gaupol. I've updated the answer ;-)

Answer (score 11):

If you prefer a command-line tool, you can try [subsync](https://github.com/spion/subsync) (requires node.js).

Note that it can also fix progressive desynchronization. This means it can fix subtitles that are late by 1 second at the beginning, but progressively get worse and are 20 seconds late at the end

disclosure: I'm the author of subsync

Answer (score 6):

For me the best option is [subtitleeditor](http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-synchronising-subtitles-with-subtitleeditor/) ( click on the link for instruction on how to use it )

It let you change frame rate in the subtitles and scaling Subtitles size ( useful for progressive desynchronization )

Install:

```
sudo apt-get install subtitleeditor
```

Comment: [HERE](https://itsfoss.com/editing-subtitles/) how to easily synchronize subtitles with this tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an online tool such as [sync subtitles](http://www.sync-subtitles.com) to easily synchronize your subtitles online.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. I notice that you have the same service that you've linked as your answer linked on your profile as well. If your main purpose on being on AU is to promote sync subtitles, you may want to read the [faq], especially the part on self promotion.

Answer (score 0):

[Subaligner](https://github.com/baxtree/subaligner/) provides a command-line interface which can automatically work out how much to shift and stretch the out-of-sync subtitles, and align them to the original video/audio files.