# subtitle syncing with timings copy-paste?

Tags: 16.04, sync, subtitle

I've got 2 subs in 2 different languages for a video.
One is synced, the other has all the right lines but wrong timing [NOT fixed nor progressive delay]: the easiest thing would be changing the timings of the latter with the ones from the former, kind of copy paste time codes.
Which subtitles editor for Ubuntu has the capabilities to accomplish/would be more suited for this task?

EDIT: Unfortunately there's no fixed delay, such that moving the subs by a certain amount of time could do it. They are simply wrongly synced (and that doesn't have to do with framerate either).
I need an editor which can kind of copy and paste the "timing" column beside the "text" column

EDIT 2: please people be civilised and read before marking as a duplicate. I'm not looking for a general sub editor, I'm looking for one with a particular feature NOT even mentioned in the question you would like to redirect me to. If it was, would you be able to point that out?
Sorry for any misunderstanding I might have created, I'm only looking for an answer, which unfortuntely is something I haven't got so far

FOR ANYONE WITH THE SAME ISSUE stumbling upon this question, the answer to what I was looking for is in the thread posted by smurfendrek123, containing nice programs that will help you (under Wine) to achieve copy-paste of timings: http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/346020-Program-to-replace-timecode-in-srt-with-timecode-from-another-srt

Comment: You probably need to adjust the FPS, and the second answer shows an option to do so: http://askubuntu.com/a/106261/158442

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vlc you can delay or speed up the subtitles by a set time.

For more software recommendations: check this thread: [What apps to sync movie subtitles easily are available for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106259/what-apps-to-sync-movie-subtitles-easily-are-available-for-ubuntu)

Also have a look at this thread: http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/346020-Program-to-replace-timecode-in-srt-with-timecode-from-another-srt

Comment: yep. But that would require me to manually adjust all the parts (since the delay is not fixed) :(

Comment: Well, it's impossible to fix that, since no program knows what delay happens when so you will always have to input each delay yourself. I suggest you get a different sub file or a different movie.

Comment: Ugh, sorry to hear that. But really, isn't there any editor which can handle the timing column like LO Calc would and copy-paste it over the timing column of the other sub file?

Comment: Where would you get that timing column? If you made it yourself, instead of typing it into LO, type it into the subtitle program?

Comment: Sorry, today it seems like I really can't make myself clear. What I'm tryng to get is copying the timings from one SRT file (who's synced correctly) and put them instead of the de-synced timings in the other SRT, alongside the text in the other language.   I need to bulk copy and bulk paste the timings, so that I don't have to insert them one by one by hand

Comment: I don't think that that exists, but if it's the case that the subs gradually run faster, you can try slowing them down/ speeding them up.

Also look at this thread: http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/346020-Program-to-replace-timecode-in-srt-with-timecode-from-another-srt

Comment: That thread! That's exactly what I've been looking for! Thank you very much!! If you put it down as an answer, I'll award you with the points

Comment: I added the link to my original answer, but if you can't award the points anymore, some upvotes are nice too :p