# How to synchronize subtitles with Subtitle Composer?

Tags: video, kde, sync, subtitle

I know how to do that with [Gnome Subtitles](https://askubuntu.com/a/363748/925128):

- opening the subtitle and the video
- pausing video when the proper subtitle line is selected
- adding a sync point at the beginning and at the end

This fixes the subtitle in 70% of cases. Adding 2-3 more intermediary points brings that to 95%.

In KDE I would prefer to use [Subtitle Composer](https://invent.kde.org/kde/subtitlecomposer), which is  Qt/KDE tool. It has many other advantages. It seems lighter, richer, with better video rendering (scrolling video is awful in Gnome Subtitles). It is cross-platform, and in Linux is also available as Appimage.

[image]

All I could find found about [synchronizing with this tool](https://github.com/maxrd2/subtitlecomposer) is:

> Quick and easy subtitle sync:
>
> ```
> Dragging several anchors/graftpoints and stretching timeline
> Time shifting and scaling, lines duration re-calculation, framerate conversion, etc.
> Joining and splitting of subtitle files
> ```

But what exactly are the steps to sync a subtitle with this tool?

What steps are the equivalent of those taken in Gnome Subtitles?

---

Edit:

Sometimes this simple trick works: select the subtitle line that you need to synchronize with a line in the movie, stop the movie at that moment, and press Shift-A (or *Times - Shift to video position*) and save.

But in most cases it's not enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quickest/easiest method to sync subtitle with Subtitle Composer is:

1. select a title near the video start and press Alt+A (Menu - Times > Toggle Anchor)
2. drag that anchored title to correct position on waveform
3. select one title near the video end and anchor this one too with Alt+A (keep first one anchored too)
4. drag second anchored title to correct position

That should be enough for synchronizing most titles as they are usually linearly distorted - otherwise keep repeating steps 3 and 4 on other titles which are off.

At some point there will be ability to sync titles using speech recognition in SC, but not yet.

Comment: In case *dragging* titles doesn't seem available, this works: select the subtitle line at the beginning, stop the movie at suited moment, press Alt-A (or *Times - Toggle anchor*) then Shift-Z (or *Times - Set Current Line Show Time*). Just that works in *some* cases; one can see within the program if it works; if it doesn't, do that again for the last line and maybe for some in between. Save.

Comment: To make it clear: **dragging the line onto the wave bar is the same as *Shift-Z (or Times - Set Current Line Show Time*)**

Answer (score 2):

I do not have a Subtitle Composer, but I would use a command prompt editor subs.

It is a very good program for shifting, streching, moving and splitting subtitles. Command prompt:

subs - convert, join, split, and re-time subtitles

If subtitles are shown too early ( 5 seconds):

```
subs -i -b 5 file.sub
```

If subtitles are for a movie in 25 fps, need to be for 24 ( actual for frame-based formats only ).

```
subs -i -a 24/25 file.sub
```

If subtitles start ok, but in 1 hour are late in 7 seconds:

```
subs -i -p 0 0 -p 1:00:00 +7 file.sub
```

Join two parts with 15-second gap

```
subs -o joined.sub -j 15 part1.sub part2.sub
```

The source is here:

```
 https://metacpan.org/release/Subtitles
```

installation is not automatic, but works ok.

It should be in Cannonical, but I do not know where and how to apply... (I am not an author)